# Weird issue with my rails path and its routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, path, routes

I'm getting a strange error with my routing. I've installed the blogit gem but I don't think this is causing this problem.

```
undefined local variable or method `locations_path'
```

Here is my routes file:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do


devise_for :users

root :to => 'locations#index'


mount Blogit::Engine => "/blog", :as => "blog" 



resources :locations do
  collection do
  get 'location'
 end
end
```

and here's my rake routes:

```
       new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)            devise/registrations#cancel

    user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy


                root        /                              locations#index
                blog        /blog                          Blogit::Engine
  location_locations GET    /locations/location(.:format)  locations#location
           locations GET    /locations(.:format)           locations#index
                     POST   /locations(.:format)           locations#create
        new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)       locations#new
       edit_location GET    /locations/:id/edit(.:format)  locations#edit
            location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)       locations#show
                     PUT    /locations/:id(.:format)       locations#update
                     DELETE /locations/:id(.:format)       locations#destroy

Routes for Blogit::Engine:
                     /posts/page/:page(.:format)            blogit/posts#index
   tagged_blog_posts        /posts/tagged/:tag(.:format)           blogit/posts#tagged
   post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     blogit/comments#create
   post_comment DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format) blogit/comments#destroy
   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                       blogit/posts#index
        POST   /posts(.:format)                       blogit/posts#create
   new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                   blogit/posts#new
   edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              blogit/posts#edit
   post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   blogit/posts#show
         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   blogit/posts#update
              DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   blogit/posts#destroy
   root        /                                      blogit/posts#index
```

Any suggestions as to why this may be happening would be great.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Basic question, restarted the server?

Comment: What type of request do you sent? GET?

Comment: another stupid question, but where are you calling your URL helper (locations_path), cause they're only available in controllers & views/helpers, not in the model.

Comment: If you visit http://<server>/locations what happens?

Comment: @felipeclopes - yep! Just retried to be sure but Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @pjam nope, it's just being called in a partial which is being pulled into a layout.

Comment: @mccannf /locations leads to my locations index page. It seems to be routing ok when I type in the URI directly. Thanks for the help so far! Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with my blogit configuration.

People can find the full thread here:

https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit/issues/8

Thanks for all your help!

James